# Fail with installing cordova watch plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install this plugin to cordova project https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch

But after installing and building the project i'm getting error "fatal error: 'MMWormholeTransiting.h' file not found"
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while using this plugin. plugin.xml is not updated in git.

Follow these steps :

1. Git clone plugin into your local machine

   `git clone https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch.git`
2. Open plugin.xml from downloaded code base. add below entries into platform tag along with other file entries :
      `<header-file src="src/ios/AppleWatch.h"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSession.h"/>
       <header-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSession.m"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionContextTransiting.h"/>
       <header-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionContextTransiting.m"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionFileTransiting.h"/>
       <header-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionFileTransiting.m"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionMessageTransiting.h"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeSessionMessageTransiting.m"/>
       <source-file src="src/ios/MMWormholeTransiting.h"/>`
3. Now you can clean and build your project but now you will get another error.
4. Add Watch Extension library from build phases.
5. Clean and build again.

Hope this helps. Please update here if it solves your issue.

Reference :
https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch/issues/30

https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch/issues/31

Comment: Please note now the plugin.xml is updated. So no need to follow these steps.